# define custom Normalisation function in matplotlib when using plt.colorbar()

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

to use matplotlib colorbar, one has to specify a `matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable` with an object from a subclass of `matplotlib.colors.Normalize`, from which the `colorbar` can know how to normalise the data into [0,1] float value.

there are only a few normalisation process provided by matplotlib, linear normalisation, log, power law etc. but in practice, we might want to use other normalisation function written by ourselves.

we can normalise the data array into [0,1] using whatever function, but without `Scalarmappable` built with `Nomalization` subclass, the colorbar won't have ticks and labels right.

I am wondering is it my understanding to matplotlib colorbar right or there is other way to do it quite easily? or perhaps we have to manually write a subclass to wrap the custom normalisation function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily subclass [`matplotlib.colors.Normalize`](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.Normalize) for this purpose. Here's an example of a piece-wise normalization class I wrote for a [previous SO question](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.Normalize):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

class PiecewiseNorm(Normalize):
    def __init__(self, levels, clip=False):
        # input levels
        self._levels = np.sort(levels)
        # corresponding normalized values between 0 and 1
        self._normed = np.linspace(0, 1, len(levels))
        Normalize.__init__(self, None, None, clip)

    def __call__(self, value, clip=None):
        # linearly interpolate to get the normalized value
        return np.ma.masked_array(np.interp(value, self._levels, self._normed))

    def inverse(self, value):
        return 1.0 - self.__call__(value)
```

For example:

```
y, x = np.mgrid[0.0:3.0:100j, 0.0:5.0:100j]
H = 50.0 * np.exp( -(x**2 + y**2) / 4.0 )
levels = [0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 20, 50]

H1 = -50.0 * np.exp( -(x**2 + y**2) / 4.0 )
levels1 = [-50, -20, -9, -6, -3, -2, -1, 0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, gridspec_kw={'width_ratios':(20, 1), 'wspace':0.05})

im0 = ax[0, 0].contourf(x, y, H, levels, cmap='jet', norm=PiecewiseNorm(levels))
cb0 = fig.colorbar(im0, cax=ax[0, 1])
im1 = ax[1, 0].contourf(x, y, H1, levels1, cmap='jet', norm=PiecewiseNorm(levels1))
cb1 = fig.colorbar(im1, cax=ax[1, 1])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: fantastic! your example just shows how easily it can be done. I mean, matplotlib docs is kinda lazy, without checking the source code I am not sure __call__ and inverse() mean. so basically just wrap normalisation function with __call__ and proceed with cautious.

Comment: To be honest I'm not entirely sure what `inverse` is actually used for - the example I gave will work without overriding that method in the derived class, but it just seemed safer to define it anyway.

Comment: by checking the source code `inverse()`, it is defined in `Normalization` subclass, such as linear, power-law and log kinds, mapping the normalised value into its original, which seems to be the face-value of the method name. the method actually is only called in a private method in `ColorbarBase`. there are very little docs and comments there, a strange land with no road sign.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for @ali_m 's idea, a few days later I think I get an idea of defining a custom `Normalization` subclass with *any* normalisation function `y=func(x)`. basically replace the private member `self._normed` with the normalised values given by any `func(self._levels)`. and when initialising the subclass, one must give the function hook to the normalisation function `func`. But be sure the `func` must be a truly normalisation.

the code below is inspired by @ali_m 's answer:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

class CustomNorm(Normalize):
    def __init__(self, levels, func, clip=None):
        # input levels
        self._levels = np.linspace(min(levels), max(levels), 10)
        # corresponding normalized values between 0 and 1
        self._normed = func(self._levels)
        Normalize.__init__(self, None, None, clip)

    def __call__(self, value, clip=None):
        # linearly interpolate to get the normalized value
        return np.ma.masked_array(np.interp(value, self._levels, self._normed))

    def inverse(self, value):
        return 1.0 - self.__call__(value)

def func(x):
    # whatever function, just normalise x into a sub-field of [0,1], 
    # it can be even [0,0.5]
    return x/50.0/2.0

y, x = np.mgrid[0.0:3.0:100j, 0.0:5.0:100j]
H = 50.0 * np.exp( -(x**2 + y**2) / 4.0 )
levels = [0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 20, 50]
# levels = [0, 50]

# H1 = -50.0 * np.exp( -(x**2 + y**2) / 4.0 )
# levels1 = [-50, -20, -9, -6, -3, -2, -1, 0]
# levels1 = [-50, 0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, gridspec_kw={'width_ratios':(20, 1), 'wspace':0.05})

im0 = ax[0, 0].contourf(x, y, H, cmap='jet', norm=CustomNorm(levels, func))
cb0 = fig.colorbar(im0, cax=ax[0, 1])
# im1 = ax[1, 0].contourf(x, y, H1, levels1, cmap='jet', norm=CustomNorm(levels1, func))
# cb1 = fig.colorbar(im1, cax=ax[1, 1])

plt.show()
```